# Hybris define product prices for PointOfService

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, price, hybris-data-hub

Hybris Out of the box doesn't provide any friendly way to define prices for products at point of service/vendor level, I need to implement price for products per store, what is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to make a composite attribute in the POS model with UserPriceGroup.

```
<typegroup name="PointOfService">
            <itemtype code="PointOfService" autocreate="false" generate="false">
                <attributes>
                    <attribute qualifier="posUsergroup" type="UserPriceGroup">
                        <persistence type="property"/>
                        <modifiers optional="false" initial="true"/>
                    </attribute>
                </attributes>
                </attributes>
            </itemtype>
        </typegroup>
```

--> PriceRow supports different prices based on UserPriceGroup.

Comment: Is the idea to set the posUsergroup in the session when the user chooses the POS?